# Incorrect display metrics for Samsung S3 on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, screen, samsung-mobile

My app has a problem with the S3 on Jelly Bean.  The DisplayMetrics returns incorrect values (360 x 640).

Here is the code I use to get the display metrics.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

I also ensured I had a minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion set in the Manifest (I noticed there was a similar issue registered that turned out to be a manifest problem)

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="12" />
```

**Note** I get the correct metrics on all the other phones (that I know of) and also with an S3 on Ice Cream Sandwich.

Any ideas where I could be going wrong?  I could make a special case for this phone, but I'd rather get to the bottom of the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with those values? they are display dimensions in dip units.

Comment: According to the docs it is the height/width in pixels: - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#heightPixels

Comment: then the only solution is to write to samsung

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer.  My manifest had: -

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    >
</supports-screens>
```

I changed it to: -

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    >
</supports-screens>
```

Works fine now :)